# A nutritionally complete diet that respects W.H.O. standards?

Tags: nutrition, diet, micronutrients, supplement

I'm looking for a way to build a diet that accounts for *every substance intake need* of an healthy adult male human, according to World Health Organization technical reports [like this one](http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/43411/1/WHO_TRS_935_eng.pdf), and tables like the following one.
So I'm looking after a diet (or diet model) that puts all that that data into practice, like [Soylent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_(food)), but with real food.

(*I only found this table in Italian. I'll welcome and promptly accept an edit with an English version*)
[image: Human Essential Intake Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stated you are looking for ***a way to build*** a diet I will supply you with a tool that I have designed. It already includes a practical example of what I eat every day.

[image]

This is not simply a table, it's a calculation tool. Instructions:

1. Research foods that you eat at https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list and http://nutritiondata.self.com/
2. Make sure the Serving size is set to 100g! I used to forget that all the time.
3. Paste the Values (for a 100g serving size) into the light grey tiles with yellow font.
4. Adjust the amount that you eat everyday with the number above the green tiles (in gramms).

If you're one of the people that eat the same thing every day like me you can use this to take creating your "perfect diets" to the next level.

I hope links are allowed on stackexchange, because this is the most important part. Get the Excel file here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4AGSo-ayQGUa3QtSG1saFVXd2M?usp=sharing

Clarifying:

- Column "A", dark grey tiles: name of Nutrients.
- Column "B", red tiles: your RDA (Recommended Dietary Allowance). Keep in mind the RDA is slightly different from the RDI (Recommended Daily Intake), research and tweak these values to your hearts content.
- Column "C", red tiles: is the Upper Limit. You should not excess this number.
- Column "D", orange tiles: is the total nutrients you consume (sum of all the green tiles of the same row)
- Column "E", orange tiles: Your Total / RDA. If you're anywhere near 100% you're good. However it will not warn you if you exceed the UL.
- Column "F", "I", "L"... grey tiles with yellow font: Insert the nutrition value for a 100g serving size of a food of your choice.
- Column "G", "J", "M"... green tiles: Calculation of nutrition value for a serving size of your choice (adjust with number above the green tiles)
- Column "H", "K", "N"... grey tiles: Percentage of RDA of the specified food

Comment: Wow! I wouldn't expect something like this to pop-out! Looks awesome! I will check the table out later. I will mark this as best answer in a day, if no other answers are posted.